# Inner join on multiple subqueries?

Tags: sql, join, count, db2, subquery

I am writing a select that contains a few subqueries (only one in snippet of code below), however I am having a hard time only returning rows where there is 1 existing row in the AIRFI_TCD subquery. I only want rows to be displayed when there is a matching CLT_ID on TSUMM and TPPPRFL tables. I tried the HAVING COUNT clause (see below), but that didn't work. I am blanking on how to join TSUMM with my subquery.

```
      SELECT RIGHT(DIGITS (A.CLT_ID),9) ||  A.PGM_ID ||
         RIGHT(DIGITS (A.PGM_ACCT_SQNBR),4) AS BN
       , ( SELECT B.XREF_NBR
           FROM GHMTUO#1.TPPPRFL B
           WHERE B.PARTIC_PRFL_TCD = '04' --AIRFI
             AND B.CLT_ID = A.CLT_ID
             AND B.BUS_PGM_ID = A.PGM_ID
             AND B.CLT_ID_TCD = '01'
             AND B.PARTIC_PRFL_EDT = (SELECT MAX(X.PARTIC_PRFL_EDT)
                                      FROM GHMTUO#1.TPPPRFL X
                                      WHERE X.CLT_ID = B.CLT_ID)
             AND B.PARTIC_PRFL_CDTTM = (SELECT MAX(Z.PARTIC_PRFL_CDTTM)
                                        FROM GHMTUO#1.TPPPRFL Z
                                        WHERE Z.CLT_ID = B.CLT_ID)
          ) AS AIRFI_TCD
  FROM RAMTUO#1.TSUMM A
  WHERE A.PGM_ID = 'RT'
  GROUP BY A.CLT_ID, A.PGM_ID, A.PGM_ACCT_SQNBR
  HAVING COUNT(AIRFI_TCD) > 1
  WITH UR;
```

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried to put the having clause inside the subquery?  What is the error you're getting?  Maybe you need `having count(airfi_tcd.xref_nbr) > 1`

Comment: I SQLCODE = -206, ERROR:  AIRFI_TCD IS NOT VALID IN THE CONTEXT WHERE
IT IS USED
I SQLSTATE   = 42703 SQLSTATE RETURN CODE

Comment: You can't reference column aliases in the same query (which you are trying to do here: `HAVING COUNT(AIRFI_TCD) > 1`. Also, in the presence of `GROUP BY` the `SELECT` list must only have aggregate functions or columns from the `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 0):

I this an INNER JOIN solution?

```
SELECT RIGHT(DIGITS (A.CLT_ID),9) ||  A.PGM_ID ||
         RIGHT(DIGITS (A.PGM_ACCT_SQNBR),4) AS BN,
       B.XREF_NBR AS AIRFI_TCD
FROM RAMTUO#1.TSUMM A INNER JOIN GHMTUO#1.TPPPRFL B ON B.CLT_ID = A.CLT_ID AND B.BUS_PGM_ID = A.PGM_ID
WHERE A.PGM_ID = 'RT' AND B.PARTIC_PRFL_TCD = '04'
   AND ...
GROUP BY A.CLT_ID, A.PGM_ID, A.PGM_ACCT_SQNBR
```

rows will only appear if there is a matching CLT_ID and a matching PGM_ID

Answer (score 0):

If you need just existence, then try this:

```
  SELECT RIGHT(DIGITS (A.CLT_ID),9) ||  A.PGM_ID ||
         RIGHT(DIGITS (A.PGM_ACCT_SQNBR),4) AS BN
  FROM RAMTUO#1.TSUMM A
  WHERE A.PGM_ID = 'RT'
  AND EXISTS 
        (
           SELECT 1
           FROM GHMTUO#1.TPPPRFL B
           JOIN 
           (
             SELECT CL
               T_ID
             , MAX(PARTIC_PRFL_EDT) PARTIC_PRFL_EDT
             , MAX(PARTIC_PRFL_CDTTM) PARTIC_PRFL_CDTTM
             FROM GHMTUO#1.TPPPRFL
             GROUP BY CLT_ID
           ) X ON X.CLT_ID = B.CLT_ID 
              AND X.PARTIC_PRFL_EDT = B.PARTIC_PRFL_EDT
              AND X.PARTIC_PRFL_CDTTM = B.PARTIC_PRFL_CDTTM
           WHERE B.PARTIC_PRFL_TCD = '04' --AIRFI
             AND B.CLT_ID = A.CLT_ID
             AND B.BUS_PGM_ID = A.PGM_ID
             AND B.CLT_ID_TCD = '01'
        )
  ;
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing I particularly like about DB2 is the ability to move complicated expressions or even subqueries into new virtual data fields thanks to JOIN TABLE (...), something like this:

```
      SELECT RIGHT(DIGITS (A.CLT_ID),9) ||  A.PGM_ID ||
         RIGHT(DIGITS (A.PGM_ACCT_SQNBR),4) AS BN
       , subq.AIRFI_TCD
  FROM RAMTUO#1.TSUMM A
    INNER JOIN TABLE
       ( SELECT B.XREF_NBR,
                COUNT(*)OVER() AS total_amount --number of matching entries
           FROM GHMTUO#1.TPPPRFL B
           WHERE B.PARTIC_PRFL_TCD = '04' --AIRFI
             AND B.CLT_ID = A.CLT_ID
             AND B.BUS_PGM_ID = A.PGM_ID
             AND B.CLT_ID_TCD = '01'
             AND B.PARTIC_PRFL_EDT = (SELECT MAX(X.PARTIC_PRFL_EDT)
                                      FROM GHMTUO#1.TPPPRFL X
                                      WHERE X.CLT_ID = B.CLT_ID)
             AND B.PARTIC_PRFL_CDTTM = (SELECT MAX(Z.PARTIC_PRFL_CDTTM)
                                        FROM GHMTUO#1.TPPPRFL Z
                                        WHERE Z.CLT_ID = B.CLT_ID)
          ) AS subq (AIRFI_TCD, total_amount) ON subq.total_amount = 1 --instead of HAVING
  WHERE A.PGM_ID = 'RT'
  WITH UR;
```

Try it, I hope it works.

Comment: You can replace TABLE with LATERAL which where introduced in SQL99. They are synonyms in Db2, but LATERAL is supported by several other vendors as well.